# get cell value from colspan with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I am running a project in which I use HTML,Javascript, And PHP Codeigniter, and I have a problem that I am trying to solve by using JavaScript.

As one can see in the table below, I have a table header JML and I am trying to count the number of items in that row using JavaScript and to place it there.

[image]

I hope result like looks like this image:

[image]

and i get log my javascript code:
 TIK
count rows 3

Following is the code I have written, however I think this is incorrect. How can I fix it?

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
function cetakPDF() {
    var table = document.getElementById('dg');
    for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
        for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
            console.log(table.rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML);
        }
    }
    console.log('count rows '+r);
}
```

here is the HTML code :

```
<table class="easyui-datagrid" id="dg" title="Raport Nilai " style="width:auto;height:250px"
        toolbar="#toolbar" data-options="rownumbers:true,singleSelect:true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-options="field:'',width:100" rowspan="2">NRIC</th>
            <th data-options="field:'',width:150" rowspan="2">Nama Siswa</th>

            <th colspan="<?php echo count($hasil); ?>" width="200" >Nilai UTS</th>
            <th data-options="field:'ss',width:100" align="center" rowspan="2">JML</th>
            <th data-options="field:'ss',width:100" align="center" rowspan="2">RT</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <?php foreach ($hasil as $item):?>
                <th  data-options="field:'listprice',width:80,align:'center'">
                    <?php echo $item->kodemapel?>
                </th>
                      <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th field="NRIC" width="100" align="center"></th>
          <th field="NAME" width="150" align="center"></th>

          <?php foreach ($hasil as $item):?>
            <th id="nilai" field="<?php echo "$item->kodemapel"; ?>" align="center"></th>
          <?php endforeach; ?>

          <th field="JML" width="50" align="center" data-options =" "></th>
          <th field="RT" width="50" align="center" data-options ="formatter:function(value,row,index){return ratarata(row);}"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: would seem simpler just to so it in php

Comment: how ? can give me example ?

Comment: you have the numbers in the php variables, just add them up

Comment: can i do without php ? can i do with javascript like my JavaScript code ?

Comment: you can do it with either but i would never do anything with js that i can do with php

Comment: sorry, can you explain with code in php? if you can do with php

Comment: i dont know the variables because you don't show them, above is only the headers hot the contents of the table